# Django: Try reverse of model's __str__() function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want a function that can have the reverse result of the model `__str__` function. For example I have:

**Model**

```py
class DepartmentModel(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    department_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.department_name
```

As part of the Custom Field `TypedModelListField` I need to convert the models string representation into an object if it exists.

Say I have object `<DepartmentModel: Finance>` which called `__str__()` returns `"Finance"`

I'd like to take string `"Finance"` and have the effects of reversing the `__str__()` function to return the object `<DepartmentModel: Finance>` if possible.

**Form**

```py
class AddDepartment(forms.Form):

    user = CustomFields.TypedModelListField(
                        queryset=DepartmentModel.objects.all())
```

**Custom Field**

```py
class TypedModelListField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value == '' or value == None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Entry cannot be empty')
        
        #####################################################################
        ### HERE I WANT TO TRY AND CONVERT __STR__ REPRESENTATION to OBJ  ###
        #####################################################################

        value = super().to_python(value)
        return value

class ListTextWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, dataset, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self._name = name
        self._list = dataset
        self.attrs.update({'list':'list__%s' % self._name,'style': 'width:100px;'})
        if 'width' in kwargs:
            width = kwargs['width']
            self.attrs.update({'style': 'width:{}px;'.format(width)})
        if 'identifier' in kwargs:
            self.attrs.update({'id':kwargs['identifier']})

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        text_html = super().render(name, value, attrs=attrs)
        data_list = '<datalist id="list__%s">' % self._name
        for item in self._list:
            data_list += '<option value="%s">' % item
        data_list += '</datalist>'
        return (text_html + data_list)
```

I must add, I want this to be dynamic so the custom field can be reapplied regardless of the model.
For example I could write (in the `to_python` function):

```py
try:
    value = DepartmentModel.objects.get(department_name=value)
except:
    raise forms.ValidationError('Department does not exist')
```

but this is explicit about the model and the model's `department_name` used in the query.

Comment: If you want to do that _reliably_ then `department_name` should be **unique** and a you should reflect the same on the fields definition: `models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes you're right it should be.

Comment: Plus from my understanding you simply want something like the user being able to type something and select the instance (the select widget can grow quite long if there are many instances). Perhaps a javascript solution would be better in that case?

Comment: This appears to be a promising package for you https://select2.org/ also there is a django package to integrate this with Django easily: https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, so the Custom Field takes the `__str__()` of the object from the queryset to form the choices of a typed list widget. The front end form POST request returns a string. I need to check if the string matches to a model via a "reverse __str__" and if so convert back to obj. Else it raises a Validation Error.